# Why is OpenID Connect considered mobile friendly compared to SAML

Tags: mobile, saml, openid-connect

I've read in multiple places that OpenID Connect is mobile friendly and SAML is not really designed for mobile. I'm new to both of these protocols but what I understood is that the mobile apps need to launch a browser equivalent (WebView) in order to handle the authentication at IDP and also to handle the redirects involved with SAML flow. Can this be avoided with OIDC?

I'm not interested in how social logins with Google etc work but scenarios where enterprises federate via OIDC. Is it even a fair statement to say that companies federate using OIDC instead of SAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAML is browser based and crytographically heavy.

OIDC is REST based - some flows e.g. client credential do not need a browser.

Enterprises that use what Microsoft calls "modern authentication" (i.e. OIDC) don't use SAML.

e.g. the default connection to an Azure AD site or O365 is OIDC.

Comment: Can you point to an example Mobile App as a reference that uses OIDC and doesn't use a browser. Many articles seem to suggest launching a WebController or Chrome Custom Tab to handle the authentication on IDP end when OIDC is used. Am I missing something here?

Comment: In the Microsoft world, this is handled by an ADAL library - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#native-application-to-web-api

Comment: An ID Token is only meant to be used by the client through a user-agent (eg.g browser) so you MAY need a browser

Comment: OIDC requires a browser for authentication and session management. As per the Authorization Code flow, PKCE flow and Implicit flow...you need a browser to issue a request to the Authorization endpoint.

Comment: "some flows e.g. client credential do not need a browser." -> isn't it the whole point of delegated access that the user does not trust the application and consequently does not want to enter credentials there? So if we're not talking about backend/m2m communication or the app vendor being same as identity provider, that OAuth2 is not necessarily mobile friendlier than SAML2?